# py2exe и иже с ним подобные для python3

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой, что для третьей версии питона нет необходимой мне сейчас утилиты py2exe. Кто может подсказать аналоги? Ну и желательно краткую документацию/инструкцию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/):

> `cx_Freeze` is a set of scripts and modules for freezing Python scripts into executables in much the same way that py2exe.

Достаточно просто использовать [Google](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pyinstaller#sclient=psy&hl=ru&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=py2exe+python+3&pbx=1&oq=py2exe+&aq=3&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=0l0l1l712l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=d2cb2d2013aac430&biw=1920&bih=1109): самая первая ссылка ;).