# Как перенести программу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5

Столкнулся с тем, что нет подробной информации про то, как передать написанную программу пользователю. Пишу на Python 3 и получаю файл .py , из личных соображений понимаю что должен каким-то образом передать пользователю все модули которые подключал и он должен как-то запустить программу)

Пожалуйста, перечислите  все возможные варианты, их плюсы и минусы и для каких OC они подходят, а так же если я использую PyQt добавляются ещё какие-то способы переноса или их становится меньше?

PS: может есть какая-то не заумная литература на эту тему?

Comment: "все возможные варианты, их плюсы  и минусы" — чересчур обширная постановка. Пользователя GUI программы обычно не волнует ни GUI framework используемый ни языки реализации — способы распространения и установки с Питоном не связаны. К примеру, VLC доступен на многих платформах и имеет соответсвенно множество способов установки.

Comment: я на cx_freeze переношу. но и тоже есть проблемы. например сборка в арче не запускается на дебиан из-за несовместимости libc.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [py2exe и иже с ним подобные для python3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/25395/py2exe-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-python3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из распространенных вариантов это формирование [PyPI пакета](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html?highlight=pypi)

После публикации вашего пакета, все что нужно будет сделать другому пользователю - просто установить его через пакетный менеджер [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip):

```
$ pip install <your-package-name>
```

Также есть вариант формировать из вашего питоньего кода deb-пакет с помощью Makefile. Пример можно найти [по этой ссылке](https://github.com/Kagami/python_app_seed).